# Minimum Distance between a Triangle and a Distance Field 3D

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles, convex-optimization

I am looking for (possibly numerical) solution to this geometric problem:

> Given a filled 3D triangle $T = \text{conv}(p_1, p_2, p_3) \subseteq R^3$, and a distance field $D(x) : R^3 \to R$, what is the point in the triangle $p^*$ which minimizes $D$, and what is the value of $d^* = D(p^*)$?

Assumptions:

- $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are coplanar 3d points, and their convex combination forms the triangle $T$.
- $D(x)$ is the minimum Euclidean distance of $x \in R^3$ to a (not necessarily convex) set $S \subseteq R^3$.  No other properties of $D$ can be assumed.
- There may be multiple solutions for $p^*$ (for instance, *D* may be constant over $T$).
- $d^* = \text{min} ~D(x)~\forall~x \in T$ exists.
- It is easy to compute the gradient  $\nabla D$.

I think it is possible to solve the problem numerically using Gradient Descent, representing the triangle as a set of linear constraints. Another possibility is to represent the triangle using Barycentric Coordinates and do gradient descent in that space rather than representing the triangle as a set of constraints.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Is $D$ necessarily a *distance field*, i.e. the distance from $x$ to the nearest point in some set $S$, or is it just an arbitrary scalar field? Because you say that no other properties of $D$ can be assumed, but a distance field is necessarily Lipschitz continuous with constant $1$. You also say that $D$ is smooth but not necessarily convex, but a nonconvex distance field is typically not smooth either (it is nondifferentiable on the medial axis of the complement of $S$). Not that any of this helps much to find the minimum, though.

Comment: D is necessarily a distance field. It is the nearest point in some set S.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding, you are seeking the closest point in $T$ to $S$, where $S$ could be nonconvex (but is perhaps connected?).
If that interpretation is correct, then a key search phrase is *collision detection*.
In computer graphics, one often must compute the closest point between two polyhedral objects to anticipate collision, and there is a large literature on the topic. If you can
approximate your set $S$ by polyhedra, then you can apply collision detection techniques.

For example:

> Ponamgi, Manocha, Lin.
>   "Incremental algorithms for collision detection between solid models."
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=218076))

A software package named SWIFT++ is maintained at the Univ. North Carolina:  [SWIFT++ link](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/SWIFT++/) :

> SWIFT++ is a collision detection package capable of detecting intersection, performing tolerance verification, computing approximate and exact distance, or determining the contacts between pairs of objects in a scene composed of general rigid polyhedral models.

To illustrate the sophistication of collision-detection
state of the art, here is a snapshot from a video showing a computation of two colliding knots,
each composed of 37,000 triangles:

---

[image: Colliding Knots]
<sub>Video: [Interactive Continuous Collision Detection for Non-Convex Polyhedra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsrCwyXXZ7E)</sub>

---

The paper describing this work is here:

> Zhang, Xinyu, Minkyoung Lee, and Young J. Kim. "Interactive continuous collision detection for non-convex polyhedra." *The Visual Computer* 22.9-11 (2006): 749-760.
>   ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00371-006-0060-0#page-1)).

Comment: I self-plagarized a bit from my answer to this MO question: "[Intersection of Polyhedra](http://mathoverflow.net/a/141730/6094)."

Comment: This is exactly the problem domain I'm coming from. I am doing PhD research involving collision detection as a subcomponent, (specifically in robotics) so I'm well aware of triangle-triangle techniques. I am looking for a more efficient way to do triangle-distancefield collision without resorting to triangle-triangle checks. My natural scene representaiton is a volumetric distance field, and I am checking triangles against this.